# Webview renders images fail when there are too many image

Tags: android, webview

In my app, when the webviews load a html contains too many image, some image may render fail, but the coresponding images are downloaded successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling DOM Storage APIs.

```
WebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```